# PostgreSQL run query as a string in place of sql file

Tags: bash, postgresql, psql

I have a need to run a query for maintenance reasons as below using psql

```
psql -U postgres -d test 'update sometbl set col1 = true;'
```

I could put the query in a sql file and run it using -f option but I really need this to run from within a bash script and don't want to have to use an additional sql file for this simple query.

Comment: `psql ... -c 'update ...'`

Answer (score 5):

You can execute a command via the psql command line interface with the parameter `-c`.

So in your example, this would be:

```
psql -U postgres -d test -c 'update sometbl set col1 = true;'
```

Refer to the documenation of psql here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/app-psql.html